# "UPSERT" a Redshift table using Kinesis Firehose

Tags: duplicates, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, upsert, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm setting up a `Kinesis Data Stream -> Firehose -> Redshift` datapipeline.

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html#duplication) say that Firehose might introduce duplicates.

To solve this case it I'm trying to use an "upsert" approach from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html).

Is it possible to set up a transaction invoke through the Firehose COPY command ?

What are the best practices ?

Thanks in advance !

Helpful code:

- the target table creation

```
create table target 
(
    key BIGINT,
    value VARCHAR
);
```

- the data format

```
{"key": 1, "value": "stub 1"}
```

- the upsert transaction

```
begin transaction;
    
    -- create a stage table like a target table
    create temp table stage (like target);

    -- populate the stage table
    COPY stage FROM 's3://<bucket-name>/<manifests-folder>/' 
    CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::<iam>:role/<role>' 
    MANIFEST format as json 'auto';

    -- delete duplicates from the target table
    delete from target using stage 
    where target.key = stage.key; 

    -- populate the target table
    insert into target
    (select * from stage);

    -- drop the stage table
    drop table stage;

end transaction;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can set up a trigger on Firehose but I recommend that you don't.  If you are using Firehose you have data coming in quickly and Firehose will COPY to Redshift as it needs.  The issue that comes up is how fast do you really want tables changing in Redshift.  Redshift is big but there are some practical limits to how fast you want to be adding incremental data to your fact tables.  This rate will depend on what transforms are needed after ingestion, how often you can afford to vacuum / analyze, how heavy is your query load / complexity, etc.  Refreshing every 5 minutes is usually possible. Faster is doable too in the right conditions.

So a process that collects up all the new data in the staging table and adds it to the target table every 1-5 minutes is way to do this at independent rates.  CloudWatch can trigger a Lambda at whatever interval you like and the Lambda can issue the SQL to Redshift.  The SQL will look like:

1. rename staging table and create a new staging table in a single
   transaction
2. in a new transaction and lock the renamed staging table exclusively so that all commits are complete before the process continues
3. ingest the renamed staging table onto the target table as you are doing above in a transaction
4. drop the renamed staging table

What is key is to use Redshift coherency to ensure that there is no data loss or duplication from the two processes, firehose and lambda, running at independent rates.  Each COPY either starts before or after the COMMIT of the staging table rename transaction.  If before, the data coming in goes to the renamed staging table and we need to be sure that the ingestion to the target table doesn't start before the COPY is complete and committed.  If after, the data goes to the new staging table.  I'd add a random number to the renamed staging table's name so that only the Lambda will use this name - this prevents name collisions if the rate of ingestion is too high for a large wave of incoming data and these processes overlap.

Comment: Thank you, @Bill, for your answer!
Did I understand right that you suggest using 3 tables: (stage, stage_renamed and target)?

Some additional info about my conditions:
1) I don't use data transformations (there are layers with raw data (S3), deduplicated data (target table) and data marts); 2) Running lambda functions each 5 minutes works for me, because I have the near-real time pipeline

Comment: Sort of.  COPYs run putting data in a staging table.  You rename this table to something else and create a new version of the COPY target table.  This makes sure no data is lost due to overlapping actions.  Then this renamed table is UPSERTed and DROPped.  So is this 2 tables but with a short lived table during the UPSERT? Is this 3 table? Or is this infinite tables as you are make a new version of the COPY target every 5min?

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It seems that now I understand your concept.
I guess we are talking about 2 long-lived tables (stage, target) and 1 short-lived (stage_renamed).

Comment: Yes if you look at these by table name.  By table id number the COPY target stage table keeps changing.

Comment: Very interesting idea, I am a bit confusing your last comment "By table id number the COPY target stage table keeps changing". The renamed stage table will keep changing but the COPY target stage table will have the same name, right?

Comment: The issue being addressed is that if the COPY & UPSERT process runs every 5 min what happens if this processing takes more than 5 min?  There will be 2 COPY/UPSERT processes trying to act on the same staging table.  This would be bad.  So at the beginning of each C/U process we rename the existing staging table (that could be still in use by the last process) and make our own version.  Redshift has no issues with this as these 2 tables have different table ids.  In this overlap case this process has a staging table and the previous process is has a staging table but they have different ids.

Comment: In step 4 you will drop the renamed staging table but if this is still in use by the previous COPY/UPSERT which will the COMMIT after the DROP to stall until it can get the appropriate lock on the table.  (Remember that the previous process is still calling this table staging, not renamed staging. This process's renamed staging is the same table id as last process's staging.) So the DROP will wait until the previous process is done.  If you speed up the rate of running C/U you could end up with many overlapped processes running (not necessarily good or bad).